# MxGraph - Add background to edge label

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm trying to add background to the edges label but it doesn't seem to be working. any suggestions?

here's my code:

```
graph.insertEdge(
  parent,
  r.id,
  r.name,
  src,
  target,
  'edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;fontSize=14;fontColor=#000;fillColor=#fff;strokeColor=black'
);
```

this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

the current result:

[image]

Comment: btw I tried add `background: #fff` using css but that doesn't seem to work on `<text>` and `<g>` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `labelBackgroundColor` style.
Like this:

```
graph.insertEdge(
 .....
 'labelBackgroundColor=red'
);
```

To figure out things like this, I would recommend you do it manually using draw.io (diagrams.net) and then just copy the style.

Comment: Hey, do you have any idea how to remove the edges using an X icon or pressing the delete key? I have been doing a lot of research but couldn't find anything :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean? To get a normal editor, you could try starting with example instead of plain mxgraph library (take a look at the "graph editor" for instance): https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/index.html